# VSCode Devcontainers Port forwarding doesn't work properly on remote server

Tags: docker, nginx, remote-server, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

### Overview

I am trying to run **VSCode Devcontainer** on my **remote server for development** with **PHP** and **Nginx**. It works perfect if I connect to the server via **VSCode SSH** and run `docker-compose.yml` manually on port **8081**. The issue is that it doesn't work when I open project in **VSCode Devcontainer** (it has white screen with infinite loads and logs are clear).

Have you ever come across this?

[Container Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvhwo.png)

### Files

*.devcontainer/devcontainer.json*

```json
{
    "name": "App",
    "dockerComposeFile": [
        "../docker-compose.yml"
    ],
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace/",
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/composer:1": {
            "version": "2.7.1"
        },
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-outside-of-docker:1": {}
    },
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client",
                "shevaua.phpcs",
                "persoderlind.vscode-phpcbf",
                "xdebug.php-debug",
                "christian-kohler.path-intellisense",
                "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash",
                "php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/local/bin/php"
            }
        }
    },
    "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile
    environment:
      PORT: 3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/workspace
    user: vscode
    command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
  php:
    container_name: php
    build: .devcontainer/images/php
    volumes:
      - ./app/public:/var/www/html
      - ./conf/php:/usr/local/etc
      - ./logs/php:/usr/local/var/logs
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - app
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: .devcontainer/images/nginx
    volumes:
      - ./app/public:/var/www/html
      - ./conf/nginx:/etc/nginx
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    depends_on:
      - php
```

*.devcontainer/Dockerfile*

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:ubuntu-22.04
```

*.devcontainer/nginx/Dockerfile*

```
ARG NGINX_VERSION=1.25
FROM nginx:${NGINX_VERSION}
```

*.devcontainer/php/Dockerfile*

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=8.3-fpm
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}
```

### What did I try

1. I tried to run `docker-compose.yml` via **VSCode SSH Remote** manually by typing `docker-compose up -d` and it works perfect. It forwards host **localhost:8081** to **localhost:8081** and I can see content of `index.php` file.

- [Content:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReGxj.png) **[localhost:8081](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReGxj.png)**
- [VSCode:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oLua.png) **[PORTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oLua.png)** [tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oLua.png)
- [Docker: compose -up d && docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cMQ4.png)

2. I tried to set up Docker host in VSCode by adding code below following **Develop Remote Host** documentation

```json
"docker.environment": {
    "DOCKER_HOST": "ssh://your-remote-user@your-remote-machine-fqdn-or-ip-here"
}
```

3. I tried to change port for all services
4. I tried to set up `launch.json` file to run PHP in workspace manually

### Guess

In general I understand why it happens. I think it forwards ports from **Docker Remote Server** to **Remote Server** instead of forwarding from **Docker Remote Server** to **Local Environment**, but how to tackle it I don't know.

### Expectations

I want to run **VSCode Devcontainer** on remote server instead of **VSCode SSH Remote**. In result, I should be able to develop in **VSCode Devcontainer** on the my own remote server. In addition, **PHP** and **Nginx** should work without any issues.